Encountered UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID from HEARTBEAT response - Kafka
I have created ProtoBuf file and using object file generated via protoc command in my code i.e.
MyEvent.java
MyEventOrBuilder.java
MyEventProtos.java

I am using Apache Kafka (Confluent) to handle the events. I created the topic and sending the message to it successfully. The issue occurs when I receive that message in my code (debugging locally). I see the message as expected. The issue occurs when I try to create builder using following lines
val builder = MyEvent.newBuilder()

when the debugger reaches here it just gets lost. Application is running but not moving forward from this debugging point, kind of stuck there. There are no error logs but some logs are generated which are as follows.
23-08-2024 15:28:45.200 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  ... - Received [topic: my.awesome.topic][offset: 8][partition: 0][key: foobar]
23-08-2024 15:30:03.708 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | myGroupid] INFO  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.handleTimedOutRequests - ... Disconnecting from node 0 due to request timeout.
23-08-2024 15:30:03.709 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | myGroupid] INFO  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.cancelInFlightRequests - ... Cancelled in-flight OFFSET_FOR_LEADER_EPOCH request with correlation id 17 due to node 0 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 78708ms, elapsed time since send: 78707ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
23-08-2024 15:30:03.713 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | myGroupid] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator.markCoordinatorUnknown - ... Group coordinator ... (id: 2174783467 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid due to cause: session timed out without receiving a heartbeat response. isDisconnected: false. Rediscovery will be attempted.
23-08-2024 15:30:03.713 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | myGroupid] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator.markCoordinatorUnknown - ... Requesting disconnect from last known coordinator ... (id: 2174783467 rack: null)
23-08-2024 15:30:03.713 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | myGroupid] INFO  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.disconnect - ... Client requested disconnect from node 2174783467
23-08-2024 15:30:04.149 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | myGroupid] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator.onSuccess - ... Discovered group coordinator ... (id: 2174783467 rack: null)
23-08-2024 15:30:04.258 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | myGroupid] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator.onSuccess - ... Discovered group coordinator ... (id: 2174783467 rack: null)
23-08-2024 15:30:05.789 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | myGroupid] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator.handle -  ... Attempt to heartbeat with Generation{generationId=142, memberId='myMemberId', protocol='range'} and group instance id Optional.empty failed due to UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID, resetting generation
23-08-2024 15:30:05.790 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | myGroupid] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator.resetStateAndGeneration ... Resetting generation and member id due to: encountered UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID from HEARTBEAT response
23-08-2024 15:30:05.790 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | myGroupid] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator.requestRejoin - ... Request joining group due to: encountered UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID from HEARTBEAT response

I googled it but found nothing. Tried parsing the json message like following but this also gets stuck
val messageDetails = Gson().fromJson(message.data as String, myEvent::class.java)

Did anyone encountered this kind of issue? or know possible solution?

The issue was the Protobuf version. I was using higher version of Protobuf i.e. libprotoc 27.3 however the parent library which was responsible for processing the protobuf was using libprotoc 3.21.12
This was causing the issue. I downgraded the protobuf version (protoc --version) and it worked fine
